# Problem with transfer of money from a Saudi bank to my account in England

Tags: international, transfer

Last October I deposited £870 salary in a Saudi bank account to be transferred to my Barclays account in the UK.  I was awaiting a Saudi bank account so the money was sent by international bank transfer endorsed by my project manager.  When I returned to the UK the money had not arrived in my account.  I contacted Barclays International Payments who were able to trace the payment.  The money was still in the Saudi bank.  I gave the cashier the correct Swift Bic and IBAN number and he took the money and gave me a receipt which I have.  On the receipt the IBAN is correct.  I have a strong suspicion there has been a deliberate routing error.  Please could suggestion my next course of action.